# How to replace the ' \\ ' with ' \ ' in a bytes file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Here is my problem: I have an encrypted bytes file like this:

```
[w\x84\x7f@\xc6\xab\xc8
```

I want to decrypt it with PyCrypto, but I find a confused bug like the following:

Code here:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES
key = 'jsfghutp'
cipher = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_ECB)
s = open('d:/Thu-Aug-2018.bin','rb').read()

cipher.decrypt(s)
```

If I run this, it will throw an error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-4fcf0e8076ca> in <module>()
----> 1 cipher.decrypt(s)

D:\Python\anaconda\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py in 
decrypt(self, ciphertext)
    293             return res
    294 
--> 295            return self._cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
    296 

ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 8 in length
```

I print the value of s:

```
s =  b'[w\\x84\\x7f@\\xc6\\xab\\xc8'
```

However this is not right, what I need is the following result:

```
>>> cipher.decrypt(b'[w\x84\x7f@\xc6\xab\xc8')
b'test aaa'
```

That is, I think I must replace the `\\\\` with `\` in the bytes file, but I failed to do it with a correct way. Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: How have you created the .bin?

Comment: Looks like you printed a string of characters to the file instead of the bytes they represent. Show how you created the file.

Comment: the content of the file is shown above mentioned

Comment: ok, I will show the code that created that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no double-backslash in your file. When you look at the `repr` of a `bytes` object, it shows all backslashes escaped, to avoid confusion between, e.g., `\n` (a newline) and `\\n` (a backslash followed by an `n`).

For example:

```
>>> s = rb'\x84'
>>> s
b'\\x84'
>>> s[0]
92
>>> chr(s[0])
'\\'
```

So, the problem you're asking about doesn't exist. There are only single backslashes in your file.

---

The actual problem is that you didn't want the four bytes backslash, x, 8, and 4, you wanted the single byte `b'\x84'`, aka `chr(0x84)`. But the four bytes are what you have in your file.

So your bug is in whatever code you used to create this file. Somehow, instead of dumping the bytes to the file, you dumped a backslash-escaped string representation of those bytes. The right place to fix it is in the code that created the file. Not writing corrupt data is always better than writing corrupt data, and then trying to figure out how to uncorrupt it.

But if it's too late for that—e.g., if you've used that broken code to encrypt a bunch of plaintext that you no longer have access to, and now you need to try to recover it—then this transformation happens to be reversible. You just have to do it in two steps.

---

First, you decode the bytes with a backslash-escape or more general unicode-escape codec:

```
>>> s=rb'[w\x84\x7f@\xc6\xab\xc8'
>>> s
b'[w\\x84\\x7f@\\xc6\\xab\\xc8'
>>> s.decode('unicode-escape')
'[w\x84\x7f@Æ«È'
```

Then you turn each Unicode character into the byte matching the same number, either explicitly:

```
>>> bytes(map(ord, s.decode('unicode-escape')))
b'[w\x84\x7f@\xc6\xab\xc8'
```

… or, somewhat hackily, by relying on Python's interpretation of Latin-1:<sup>1</sup>

```
>>> s.decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin-1')
b'[w\x84\x7f@\xc6\xab\xc8'
```

Again, those backslashes aren't actually in the string, that's just how Python represents a `bytes`. For example, if you put that in `b`, `hex(b[2])` is `0x84` for byte `\x84`, not `0x5c` for the backslash character.

---

Your creation code is the real problem:

```
with open(file,'a') as f:

    f.write(str(encrypt_text).split("b'")[1].split("'")[0])
    f.close()
```

You’re converting the bytes to their string representation—with the `b` prefix, the quotes around it, and the backslash escaping for every byte that isn’t printable ASCII, then stripping off the `b` and the quotes, then encoding the whole thing as UTF-8 by writing it to a text-mode file.

What you want to do is just open the file in binary mode and write the bytes to it:

```
with open(file, 'ab') as f:
    f.write(encrypt_text)
```

(Also, you don't want to call `f.close()`; the `with` statement already takes care of that.)

Then you can read the file in binary mode and just decrypt the bytes as-is.

(Or, if you really want the file to be human-editable or something, you want to pick a format that’s designed to be human-editable and easily reversible, like `hexlify` or `base64`, not “whatever Python does to represent `bytes` objects for debugging”.)

---

<sup>1. Unicode is guaranteed to line up with Latin-1 for all characters in Latin-1. Python interprets that to mean that Latin-1 should encode every byte from 0-255 as code point 0-255, instead of just the ones actually defined in ISO-8859-1. Which is valid, since ISO-8859-1 doesn't say what to do with bytes that it doesn't define, but not every tool will agree with Python.</sup>

Comment: Nice trick with `unicode-escape`! I thought `literal_eval` is the only cure in such unfortunate circumstances. About unicode lining up with latin-1 - I guess it happens only for UTF-8? E. g. UTF-16 will always have at least two bytes characters.

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 No, UTF-8 does _not_ line up with Latin-1, except for characters 0-127. For characters 128-255, UTF-8 takes two bytes. But _Unicode_—the abstract code points from 0 to 1.1M—lines up with Latin-1 for the whole range 0-255.

Comment: My first thought wouldn't mention unicode but use `ast.literal_eval("b'{}'".format(s))` (reversing what `repr` does). Might be a different issue with data containing quotes, though. Better second variant: `codecs.escape_decode(s)`

Comment: The reversible solution proposed here relies on `str.decode()` but that method does not exist (in Python 3).

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the file contains *a textual representation of a bytes string* (`[w\x84\x7f@\xc6\xab\xc8`), but not actually the bytes themselves. You whether write the file properly:

```
with open('/tmp/file', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b'[w\x84\x7f@\xc6\xab\xc8')
```

Then you won't have issues with reading it:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/file', 'rb') as f: f.read()
<<< b'[w\x84\x7f@\xc6\xab\xc8'
```

Or interpret the representation saved in your file via `ast.literal_eval`, though this is really unadvisable in this case.

The bottom line is: always know what types you're operating with - strings (unicode) or bytes, and keep in mind that when you print bytes in the console, you see the representation (this \xa0-like stuff), not the bytes themselves, because some bytes don't have a printable form.